# Obfuscating CakePHP code

Tags: cakephp, obfuscation

We have a commercial application created on CakePHP. I'm about to install it on a client's server, so we'd like to protect my code from being modyfied and/or copied and reselled, changing trial period terms, etc.

I want to know if obfuscating the Cake PHP code breaks Cake specific libraries, or make the application unusable.

I've been searching on this forum and over internet and found several options for obfuscating PHP code, but none related to CakePHP. (I just asked to some of the commercial tools providers if they support Cake obfuscating but haven't received an answer yet).

Does anybody know if this is possible or if there's a better approach to do that?

I'll try to use one of the trial versions of the commercial tools this weekend, but if someone has an advice about this would be great

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My company, Semantic Designs, is one of the commercial vendors.

With a decent obfuscator [(ahem :)](http://www.semanticdesigns.com/Products/Obfuscators/PHPObfuscator.html) you shouldn't have any trouble doing this.  You need to tell the obfuscator somehow (with ours you just provide a list of symbol names) what identifiers have to be retained as cleartext (e.g., any calls to the CakePHP framework), and any public APIs your software may offer.

Comment: that sound nice, let me make a test with your evaluation version :). thx

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend, you give it a shot and try it out.
Usually, an obfuscator should obfuscate frameworks, too. It should be independent of what kind of PHP Code you use.

Test it in a test environment. If it's successful, you can enroll it to your production environment.

Comment: There may be a few problems with routing though..and possibly other "cake magic" things as well.

Comment: that's something i'm worried about actually, since cake relies on controller function names to be mapped to the view file names :S

Comment: well try this: the view, controller and model filenames should be the same, but with obfuscated code.